# StringVar() on messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

In tkinter, python, I'm trying to make a 'prank' program for my tutor so I can show what I've learnt in tkinter, yet I'm having an error using `StringVar()`.
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1x1")
secs = StringVar()
sec = 60
secs.set("60")
def add():
    global secs
    global sec
    sec += 1
    secs.set(str(sec));
    root.after(1000, add)
add()
messagebox.showinfo("Self Destruct", "This computer will self destruct in {} seconds".format(str(secs)))
```

When I execute this code I get the correct message yet I do not get a counting number, I get `PY_VARO`. I should be getting a number, counting down from 60.
Thanks.

Comment: use stringvar.get() to catch the value of StringVar(). In your case -  messagebox.showinfo("Self Destruct", "This computer will self destruct in {} seconds".format(str(secs.get())))

Comment: Have you searched this site for questions related to `PY_VAR0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a value out of a [StringVar](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html), use the `.get()` method, instead of `str(...)`.

```
"This computer will self destruct in {} seconds".format(secs.get())
```

However, in your case there is no point using a StringVar, since this object is not bound to any Tk controls (your `messagebox.showinfo` content will *not* be changed dynamically). You could as well just use a plain Python variable directly.

```
"This computer will self destruct in {} seconds".format(sec)
```

A proper use of StringVar looks like this:

```
message = StringVar()
message.set("This computer will self destruct in 60 seconds")
Label(textvariable=message).grid()
# bind the `message` StringVar with a Label.

... later ...

message.set("This computer is dead, ha ha")
# when you change the StringVar, the label's text will be updated automatically.
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but its the best alternative to it. Thanks :)